# Make maven-enforcer-plugin dependency convergence rule ignore minor version of artifact

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-enforcer-plugin

I want to introduce `maven-enforcer-plugin` in my maven project but don't want to compare the bug fix versions while evaluating the rules.

Ex.: `groupId-artifactId-X.Y.A` and `groupId-artifactId-X-Y-B` should not be treated as rule failure.

The current plugin configuration looks like following

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-versions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>1.8</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                                <banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions/>
                                <dependencyConvergence/>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

If an artifact, let's say `aws-java-sdk` is being pulled in as transitive dependency from two different directly listed dependencies, the plugin should NOT raise an error if the versions of `aws-java-sdk` only differ for minor version like `1.21.667` and `1.21.700`. 
It should only raise an error if feature/major versions are different like `1.21.667` and `1.17.111`

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by: `groupId-artifactId-X.Y.A and groupId-artifactId-X-Y-B ` are `X.Y.A` and `X-Y-B` meant to be versions? Or are those things part of the `artifactId`?

Comment: @khmarbaise If an artifact, let's say aws-java-sdk is being pulled in as transitive dependency from two different directly listed dependencies, the plugin should NOT raise an error if the versions of aws-java-sdk only differ for minor version like 1.21.667 and 1.21.700.

If should only raise an error if feature/major versions are different like 1.21.667 and 1.17.111

Comment: As JFMeier says write an enforcer rule on your own...cause currently implemented rules are comparing the whole version and do not ignore the bug fix part... You can of course make a pull request also to the maven-enforcer-plugin ...would be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with the current rule.

You need to write your own enforcer rule for that.